# Qt Creator - How to remove Clang Code Model

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator

I started using Qt a couple months ago. It's been fine and easy to use. Last night I updated it and something messed everything up. I could not run qmake nor figure out how to fix it. So I uninstalled and reinstalled it. Now it is using the Clang model. I'm not sure if it was before but I don't think it was. Now the autocomplete is messed up. When creating the definition of a function in a .cpp file, the autocomplete won't fill in the parameters like it used to. Also, sometimes type names will become invisible. I know there are characters there, but I can't see them. And I can no longer Ctrl + Click a variable or function to hyperlink to definitions and things. Anyways. I would love to get rid of Clang and go back to what I was using before. I've looked everywhere, but can't figure it out. I am currently using QtCreator 4.7.0 and Qt 5.11.1. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Uncheck _Help/Plugins/C++/ClangCodeModel_ and restart QtCreator.

Answer (score 12):

Go into Help->About Plugins and uncheck the Clang code model plugin.  You have to restart qt creator after that to make it take effect.  I had the same problem when debugging a unit test.  I was debugging code not in the project itself and it was dying repeatedly on me sending tons of kernel messages.