# Qt creator: "Warning: The code model could not parse an included file..."

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have updated Qt Creator to the latest version (4.7.0) and now I have this warning when opening my projects:

```
Warning: The code model could not parse an included file, which might lead to slow or incorrect code completion and highlighting, for example
    xmmintrin.h:818:1: error: definition of builtin function '_mm_getcsr'
    emmintrin.h:1:1: note: in file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/emmintrin.h:1:
    emmintrin.h:31:10: note: in file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/emmintrin.h:31:
```

Is this a bug and how to fix this please? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As far as i know Qt Creator 4.6.2 is the official version of creator shipped with Qt 5.11.1, although technically 4.7 is not in beta, it is far from bug free.  I suggest to stick with Qt Creator 4.6

Comment: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/07/18/qt-creator-4-7-0-released/ states that clang code model is on by default, you can disable it and use built-in model and see if the issue persists. The link has the explanation on how to turn off clang model

Comment: @Gurushant Thanks. Indeed, this problem caused by the ClangCodeModel plugin. The warning is not shown if it's disabled. Anyway this is only a warning that I can ignore and I think I will leave ClangCodeModel enabled to try it.

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: @Gurushant Please post an answer so that I can accept ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt How do I remove Clang Code Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662932/qt-how-do-i-remove-clang-code-model)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/07/18/qt-creator-4-7-0-released/ states that clang code model is on by default. The warning is thrown by the Clang code model plugin. You can disable it or try earlier qt creators such as 4.6.2

Comment: Thanks. This issue will be fixed in 4.7.1: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-21034.

Comment: For anyone searching for how to turn clang off: Disable the checkbox at Help > About Plugins (Windows/Linux), Qt Creator > About Plugins (macOS) (copied from Eike Zilleer at http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/07/18/qt-creator-4-7-0-released/)

Comment: I just installed Qt Creator 4.7.1 and I still get this warning.

Comment: @Gurushant, disabling got rid of the warnings, but intellisense got affected too as a result. Does 4.6.2’s plugin work better?

Comment: @armanalli, 4.6.2 does not have clang model, so you are stuck with normal intellisense that you used to have before

Comment: @Gurushant, but I have intellisense this way too, just not as good as it was with clang model. Are you saying that downgrading to 4.6.2 from 4.7.1 will give me better intellisense?

Comment: @armanali sorry if i created a confusion, no i don't think it will give better result. I just wanted to clear that earlier version did not have clang model so it feels good to use as it is not buggy.

Comment: I disabled the clang plugins on qtcreator in 4.8, but when I'm editing the code, it won't even show markers for normal syntax errors like missing semicolon etc.