# 'QMainWindow' file not found

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

the program works, but I don't like these errors

in mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow> //'QMainWindow' file not found

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

because of this, errors also appear in the main file

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h" //In included file: 'QMainWindow' file not found

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

the program still works, but I would still like to know the solution to the problem

Comment: Define "the program works". It compiles and runs, but your IDE displays these errors? Then your IDE is not correctly configured and can't find Qt, but you need to tell us more about it.

Comment: installing Qt creator, I chose the packages: 64-bit MSVC 2019 index, Qt5 Compatibility Module, Qt version 7.0.1 creator CDB debugger, Debugging tools for Windows, 64-bit CMake version, for example 3.21.1, Ninja 1.10.2 (all for Qt 6.3.0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the Qt version registered in Options > Kits > Qt Versions, and does it show any error/warning icon? Does the Kit that you use for the project have the Qt version set? Does the Kit show any warnings/errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737644/18282426

so, select from above `help` -> `About modules...` and disable `ClangCodeModel`